# How-to make salt hash using PHP to register new account from web?

Tags: php, security, authentication, sha1, azerothcore

What would be the PHP algorithm to authenticate an AzerothCore account (make salt and verifier) after the `sha_pass_hash` field [has been removed](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/commit/485f7e76391a5bbf1af6b3219d27db721af38440)?

Before we used:

```php
$sha_pass_hash = getPasswordHash($account_name, $password);
```

How does it work now? How to make salt and verifier to register a new account?

Can anyone provide some detailed instruction with an example?

Answer (score 2):

I've just did for the acore-cms here https://github.com/azerothcore/acore-cms/pull/20/files

I even post for a quick view the code to calculate the password with the salt:

```php
function CalculateSRP6Verifier($username, $password, $salt)
{
    // algorithm constants
    $g = gmp_init(7);
    $N = gmp_init('894B645E89E1535BBDAD5B8B290650530801B18EBFBF5E8FAB3C82872A3E9BB7', 16);

    // calculate first hash
    $h1 = sha1(strtoupper($username . ':' . $password), TRUE);

    // calculate second hash
    $h2 = sha1($salt.$h1, TRUE);

    // convert to integer (little-endian)
    $h2 = gmp_import($h2, 1, GMP_LSW_FIRST);

    // g^h2 mod N
    $verifier = gmp_powm($g, $h2, $N);

    // convert back to a byte array (little-endian)
    $verifier = gmp_export($verifier, 1, GMP_LSW_FIRST);

    // pad to 32 bytes, remember that zeros go on the end in little-endian!
    $verifier = str_pad($verifier, 32, chr(0), STR_PAD_RIGHT);

    return $verifier;
}
```

Remember to install the **php-gmp** library.

If you need to create an account you can use this to generate the salt:

```php
// generate a random salt
$salt = random_bytes(32);
```

These code is strongly inspired by the MasterKing32 CMS.